# InstallShield, Virtual Studio, Visual Basic (ADD MYSQL INTO INSTALLATION)

Tags: mysql, installshield

I am working with window application and want to create full setup of this application. I am using MySql to save/retrieve data. What I want, I want to install MySql on system if it doesn't exist on that system before installation of this application.

Simply I want my application to follow following steps before install:-

Check if MySql is exist on system or not.
Install MySql if it is not installed on system.
Finally after install required softwares to run this application the application should be install.
For this purpose i am using "InstallShield 2013". But when I am trying to make setup with this it doesn't allow MySql to appear in "Installation Requirements" section.

Please help me to resolve this that how InstallShield 2013 can allow MySql to appear in Installation requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the MySQL install creates any registry keys. If it does, then get the installer to check for a value in that path (using the registry search functionality) and store one of the values (the install directory for instance).

Then you check for that value you stored in the "installation requirements" section.